# Install Windows 7 x64 from a separate partition on same hard drive (no DVD/USB)?

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, installation, partitioning

I'm currently running Windows XP 32-bit, and want to install Windows 7 64-bit. However, my DVD drive is broken, and the only USB sticks I have lying around are USB 1.1 only (SLOW!). So I tried (as suggested would work for a USB stick by several online guides):

1. Created new primary partition (formatted NTFS)
2. Set that partition as active
3. Copied contents of Win7 x64 ISO
4. Downloaded the 32-bit bootsect.exe
5. Ran `bootsect /nt60 F:`

However, when I boot into the new partition, I only see a blinking cursor on a blank screen; nothing happens. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did this once with a computer. I had no DVD or USB with me, so this is what I did.

1. Download the iso from DigitalRiver.
2. Open Disk Management (diskmgmt.msc).
3. Shrink your current drive by 5GB.
4. Format the unallocated space in NTFS.
5. Assign it a drive letter. I recommend using Z:, as it is easy to remember and to use.
6. Extract the files in the ISO using 7z to your new partition you just created.
7. Using EasyBCD, go to the "Add New Entry" tab.
8. Click on WinPE.
9. Give your boot entry a name. I used Windows 7 Installation
10. In the third box, select YourDrive:\Sources\Boot.wim
11. Save it.
12. Reboot.
13. When the boot menu comes up, select the entry you created using EasyBCD.
14. When the installation screen comes up, follow the instructions.
15. Enjoy your Windows 7 installation.

Note: During the installation, I wiped my other partitions and installed it on the wiped partitions. If you want to upgrade, select upgrade instead of Custom.

Answer (score 0):

if by `boot into the new partition` you meant `set it active, and reset` , tring boot the new partition from windowsxp boot manager ( add a term for win7 setup loader into `boot.ini`, i guess ) may helps.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Windows7 from a separate partition of same hard drive using [Windows 7 USB/DVD download tool](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool) once upon a time. This may help you, if you doesn't meet another issue.